# 'alignof' was not declared in this scope - C++

Tags: c++

El siguiente código me da el error 'alignof' was not declared in this scope. Uso Dev-C++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    cout << "Alignment of char: " << alignof(char) << endl; 
    cout << "Alignment of pointer: " << alignof(int*) << endl; 
    cout << "Alignment of float: " << alignof(float) << endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta función aparece a partir de C++11. ¿Puede ser que estés compilando bajo otra versión anterior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es ir a ***Herramientas >> Opciones del Compilador >> Configuración >> Generación de Código >> Language Standard*** y ahi es donde seleccionas **GNU C++11**